# More efficient way to select element from huge data frame

Tags: r

I have a huge data frame:

```
library(gtools)
a<-permutations(2,20,v=c(0,1),repeats.allowed=TRUE)
a<-as.data.frame(a)
```

And I have 100 random strings:

```
set.seed(123)

b<-replicate(100,sample(c(0,1),20, replace=T))
```

I would like to identify the row numbers in  in `'a'` that corresponds to each column in `'b'`.

Since `'a'` is huge this process takes quite some time.

right now I am using the following method:

```
sapply(1:100, function(x)  which(colSums(t(a)==as.numeric(b[,x]))==20L))
```

This process takes a lot of time.
I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what "identify the row numbers in `a` that correspond to each column in `b`" means.  Do you just want the first 100 rows of `a`?

Comment: No, I mean that you take each column in 'b' as a vector identify the corresponding row number in 'a' and repeat for each column of b. Does that help?

Comment: it should be a vector of row numbers specifying for each column in 'b' the corresponding row in 'a'

Comment: I don't understand why are you using `colSums` as the column sums are not unique. Also, why are you usig `as.numeric`? `b` is already a numeric matrix

Comment: You should provide a much smaller set of matrices to use as an example, and provide a desired result based off that.

Comment: @RichardScriven sure but I provided the large matrix to show that the computation is really slow. most methods will only break down if applied to the large matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Represent the columns as digits by thinking of them as bit strings, then use %in% for fast look-up

```
library(gtools)
a <- permutations(2,20,v=c(0,1),repeats.allowed=TRUE)
a <- as.data.frame(a)

set.seed(123)
b <- replicate(100, sample(c(0, 1), 20, replace=TRUE))

a1 <- colSums(t(a) * 2^(0:19))
b1 <- colSums(b * 2^(0:19))
```

which produces

```
> head(which(a1 %in% b1))
[1]  1191  9434 14502 19812 30619 34313
```

To deal with duplicates, consider this smaller example

```
b1 <- c(1, 3, 3, 5, 4)
a1 <- c(3, 4, 8)
```

Discover the unique b1 values, and create a list that maps from the unique values to the index in the original values

```
ub1 <- unique(b1)
umap <- unname(split(seq_along(b1), match(b1, ub1)))
```

Now match the a1 to the unique b1, decide which to keep (are not NA), and look up the matches in the unique map

```
m <- match(a1, ub1)
keep <- which(!is.na(m))
keepmap <- umap[m[keep]]
```

Finally, use keepmap to figure out how many times each kept value needs to be replicated (because it maps to multiple original values) and create a data.frame of the results

```
len <- sapply(keepmap, length)
data.frame(ai=rep(keep, len),
           a1=rep(a1[keep], len),
           b1=unlist(unname(keepmap)))
```

So a complete function is

```
matchrows <-
    function(a, b)
{
    ## encode
    a1 <- colSums(t(a) * 2^(0:19))
    b1 <- colSums(b * 2^(0:19))

    ## match to unique values
    ub1 <- unique(b1)
    m <- match(a1, ub1)
    keep <- which(!is.na(m))

    ## expand unique matches to original coordinates
    umap <- unname(split(seq_along(b1), match(b1, ub1)))
    keepmap <- umap[m[keep]]

    len <- sapply(keepmap, length)
    data.frame(ai=rep(keep, len),
               bi=unlist(unname(keepmap)),
               value=rep(a1[keep], len))
}
```

Comment: Data are indeed 0s and 1s, but the method you suggest does not work for me. match() produces NA's and %in% produces integer(0)

Comment: the data is exactly in the same one as in the example above. I very much appreciate your help and it would be great if the method you suggest could work

Comment: @user1723765 I completed the code chunk so that you can copy/paste

Comment: I only have one more issue. Lets assume that 'b' can have duplicates. for example the 2nd and 3rd column are both [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ]. in this case which() will only identify the column number for one of the two, and the resulting vector will be of size smaller than 20.

Comment: @user1723765 I don't understand where 'size smaller than 20' comes from, or what form you want the final result to take. Why not add to your question with something (a short example, since we see the speed issue now) illustrating the problem and a 'slow' or hand-made solution?

Comment: Simply if not all rows in 'b' are unique then your code will only display the row numbers for unique elements.